# How to create Link server to connect Oracle database?

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle, oracle12c, sql-server-2014-express

I just used this command to install OraOLEDB.Oracle

```
install.bat all c:\oracle odac
```

I've  tested .udl file it's working fine!!!  But when I test link sever I'm getting error.

SQL SERVER Information as below

```
Microsoft SQL Server 2014 - 12.0.2000.8 (Intel X86) 
Feb 20 2014 19:20:46 
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation
Express Edition on Windows NT 6.3 <X64> (Build 15063: ) (WOW64)
```

Oracle information

```
Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.1.0.2.0 - 64bit Production
PL/SQL Release 12.1.0.2.0 - Production
"CORE   12.1.0.2.0  Production"
TNS for 64-bit Windows: Version 12.1.0.2.0 - Production
NLSRTL Version 12.1.0.2.0 - Production
```

OS information

```
window 10
64 Bit
```

**ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:**

> An exception occurred while executing a Transact-SQL statement or
>   batch. (Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo)
>
> The OLE DB provider "MSDAORA" for linked server SQL2ORACLE reported an
>   error. The provider did not give any information about the error.
>   Cannot initialize the data source object of OLE DB provider "MSDAORA"
>   for linked server SQL2ORACLE. (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 7399)

[image][image][image]

---

Answer (score 1):

Right click on the provider (MSDAORA in your case) and click on Properties. This will open the providers properties. Ensure that "Allow inprocess" is checked.

Comment: any one help for this issue